# How do you read the mathematical equation of a plane in $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: calculus, 3d

I am reading the book "An Illustrative Guide to Multivariable and Vector Calculus" by
Stanley j. Miklavcic.
On page 4 in section "A plane in 3-space" says that:
"The equation of a plane in $\mathbb R^3$, expressed mathematically as
$P = \{(x, y, z) : ax + by + cz = d; \;a, b, c \; not\; all\; zero.\}$" How do you read this notation?

Comment: That really should be "$P = \{(x, y, z) : ax + by + cz = d\}$; $a,b,c$ not all zero."

Comment: I would read that as "the set of all points in [tex]R^3[/tex], (x, y, z) such that a times x+ b times y+ c times z is equal d".

Comment: Could we also read it as "the set of all points (x, y, z) in $\mathbb{R^3}$, such that a times x+ b times y+ c times z is equal d"?